# Unity when I click a button another gets activated (BUG) c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two buttons. one activates a method that creates a cube, and one create a purple block (see all in video). when I click one button it activates the other button. can anybody help?

[The Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iieoTKEEjBP3YTcEurWmVVDbZykauXVO/view?usp=sharing)

Here is some code:

Button 1 activates this method:

```
public void AddObsticale(int unit)
{
    Vector3 unitPos = u.Units[unit].transform.position;
    arrow.transform.position =new Vector3(unitPos.x + 4.5f, unitPos.y + 1, unitPos.z - 5f);
    arrow.SetActive(true);
    StartCoroutine(ArrowChoose());
}

IEnumerator ArrowChoose()
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return));
    GameObject g = Instantiate(obsticlePrefab, new Vector3(0, 0.5f, arrow.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity, gameObject.transform);
    arrow.SetActive(false);
}
```

Button 2 (which should not be activated) activates this method:

```
public void AddUnit()
{
    count++;
    GameObject g = Instantiate(unitPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, (count - 1) * unitSize.z), Quaternion.identity, unitsParent.transform);
    units.Add(g);
    unitText.text = "Units: " + count;
}
```

Comment: Maybe something wrong with the calling objects/events or the delegate pipeline?
It will help if you are able to share some code.

Comment: You shouldn't post it as a video. For example I am at work atm, and I can't watch a video, therefore I can't help you. Also, some people won't bother with your question, cause they don't want to spend time for that. So always post your code

Comment: I put some code up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem:

The problem was in this line:

```
yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return));
```

the return key activates the button automatically, because of unity, as soon as I changed the key to a different one, say `KeyCode.V` the problem was gone!